# How to convert an IP address to a FQDN pointing back to it?

Tags: dns

I am looking for a way to convert an IP address, from the public or private address space to a fully qualified domain name that would resolve as the original address.

I remember that I found this kind of dynamic DNS service few months back but after spending more than an hour googling I was still unable to find it again.

Now let me also explain why this is so important for software development: **testing**. By being able to generate hostnames that do resolve to their allocated IP you can easily perform proper testing on SSL and reverse checks on your software.

Workflow example:

- allocate an instance, you end up with an IP 1.2.3.4
- you name this instance `1-2-3-4-tester0.<some_dyn_dns>` which will resolve to 1.2.3.4 because its name, even **without you needing to register** it on some_dyn_dns, that's only based on its name.
- The suffix "-tester0" would be ignored by some_dyn_dns server (is only useful for humans)

So to reiterate: this is to be used in places where you cannot (or don't want to) use an IP address.

Comment: like this http://xip.io/ ?

Comment: @DusanBajic that's what I was looking for, please make it an answer. It may not fully work because it cannot be used as search domain but that's the kind of service I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since just he URL http://xip.io/ is too simple to deserve an answer of its own, I will also provide the google query that led me to it (I have not heard of the site before):

https://www.google.com/search?q=public+name+to+ip+resolver+wildcard